# Fastest way of generating numpy arrays or randomly distributed 0s and 1s

Tags: python, numpy, random

I need to generate masks for dropout for a specific neural network.
I am looking at the fastest way possible to achieve this using numpy (CPU only).

I have tried:

```
def gen_mask_1(size, p=0.75):
    return np.random.binomial(1, p, size)


def gen_mask_2(size, p=0.75):
    mask = np.random.rand(size)
    mask[mask>p]=0
    mask[mask!=0]=1
    return mask
```

where `p` is the probability of having `1`

The speed of these two approaches is comparable.

```
%timeit gen_mask_1(size=2048)
%timeit gen_mask_2(size=2048)

45.9 µs ± 575 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
47.4 µs ± 372 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Are there faster methods?

**UPDATE**

Following the suggestions got so far, I have tested a few extra implementations. I couldn't get `@njit` to work when setting `parallel=True` (`TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: convert to parfors)`), it works without but, I think, less efficiently.
I have found a python binding for Intel's `mlk_random` (thank you @MatthieuBrucher for the tip!) here: https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl_random
So far, using mlk_random together with @nxpnsv's approach gives the best result.

```
@njit
def gen_mask_3(size, p=0.75):
    mask = np.random.rand(size)
    mask[mask>p]=0
    mask[mask!=0]=1
    return mask

def gen_mask_4(size, p=0.75):
    return (np.random.rand(size) < p).astype(int)

def gen_mask_5(size):
    return np.random.choice([0, 1, 1, 1], size=size)

def gen_mask_6(size, p=0.75):
    return (mkl_random.rand(size) < p).astype(int)

def gen_mask_7(size):
    return mkl_random.choice([0, 1, 1, 1], size=size)

%timeit gen_mask_4(size=2048)
%timeit gen_mask_5(size=2048)
%timeit gen_mask_6(size=2048)
%timeit gen_mask_7(size=2048)

22.2 µs ± 145 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
25.8 µs ± 336 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
7.64 µs ± 133 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
29.6 µs ± 1.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Probably not using numpy random number generators. Perhaps by using MKL directly (https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/639846)

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I am open to alternatives, the mask needs to be a np.array at the end, so I will need to do the conversion anyway. But if you know a faster way of generating random digits in python please share it.

Comment: It might be faster, but nothing for certain. MKL has routines for this (https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-vrngbinomial#5A64C21C-BE1E-42C8-9A56-A672C45762E9), but there is no example to create the state and call the function from Python.

Comment: Does the code have to handle a probability `p` with an arbitrary value between 0 and 1, or would it be acceptable to handle a smaller set of allowed fractions?

Comment: This version of `gen_mask_2` runs faster than either of your atempts `(np.random.rand(size) < p).astype(int)`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser a smaller set of probability would be acceptable.

Comment: @nxpnsv your solution is the fastest so far, please add it as an answer. I can't get numba working though. Still trying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment the question the implementation

```
def gen_mask_2(size, p=0.75):
    mask = np.random.rand(size)
    mask[mask>p]=0
    mask[mask!=0]=1
    return mask
```

can be improved, by using that comparison gives an `bool` which then can be converted to `int`. This removes the two comparisons with masked assignments you otherwise have, and it makes for a pretty one liner :)

```
def gen_mask_2(size, p=0.75):
    return = (np.random.rand(size) < p).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) compiler and make things faster by applying `njit` decorator on your functions. Below is an example for a very large `size`

```
from numba import njit

def gen_mask_1(size, p=0.75):
    return np.random.binomial(1, p, size)

@njit(parallel=True)
def gen_mask_2(size, p=0.75):
    mask = np.random.rand(size)
    mask[mask>p]=0
    mask[mask!=0]=1
    return mask

%timeit gen_mask_1(size=100000)
%timeit gen_mask_2(size=100000)
```

---

```
2.33 ms ± 215 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
512 µs ± 25.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `numpy.random.choice`, with an input of 0s and 1s where the proportion of 1s is `p`.  For example, for `p` = 0.75, use `np.random.choice([0, 1, 1, 1], size=n)`:

```
In [303]: np.random.choice([0, 1, 1, 1], size=16)
Out[303]: array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

This is faster than using `np.random.binomial`:

```
In [304]: %timeit np.random.choice([0, 1, 1, 1], size=10000)
71.8 µs ± 368 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [305]: %timeit np.random.binomial(1, 0.75, 10000)
174 µs ± 348 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

To handle an arbitrary value for `p`, you can use the `p` option of `np.random.choice`, but then the code is slower than `np.random.binomial`:

```
In [308]: np.random.choice([0, 1], p=[0.25, 0.75], size=16)
Out[308]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])

In [309]: %timeit np.random.choice([0, 1], p=[0.25, 0.75], size=10000)
227 µs ± 781 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I wonder if the hybrid of your answer and mine would be even faster. i.e., using `np.random.choice` and applying `njit` decorator